# JavaScript- find text within a page and jump to location in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with a large list of records (say 250+ rows of data in a table) and want to be able to just visit the page, immediately start typing, and have it jump me to the first row that matches the text I have typed.

Ideally, if I then continued to type more characters so the first match doesn't match anymore, it could then continue to respond to my input and jump me to the new match.

I've tried with window.find() but haven't had much success... can anyone reccomend a working solution?

I'm essentially looking for the equivalent to hitting 'CTRL-F' on my keyboard... except without the need to hit CTRL-F to make it happen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the tricky part of this is actually the accepting of user input intelligently.  Therefore, I'd say the best thing to do is to pass off your searching to an autocomplete-type plugin.  Once the page is ready, you pass the focus to an input text box, and then let the plugin do its magic as you search...

For example, you could use the [quicksearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) plugin.

Then given a table of data and an input like this:

```
<input id="searcher" type="text" name="searcher">
```

You could have a ready function that looks like this:

```
$('#searcher').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {
    'delay': 100,
    'bind': 'keyup keydown',
    'show': function() {
        if ($('#searcher').val() === '') {
            return;
        }
        $(this).addClass('show');
    },
    'onAfter': function() {
        if ($('#searcher').val() === '') {
            return;
        }
        if ($('.show:first').length > 0){
            $('html,body').scrollTop($('.show:first').offset().top);
        }
    },
    'hide': function() {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    },
    'prepareQuery': function(val) {
        return new RegExp(val, "i");
    },
    'testQuery': function(query, txt, _row) {
        return query.test(txt);
    }
});

$('#searcher').focus();
```

Try it out here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZLhAd/369/

**EDIT**: other answer/comment added in to make the input fixed and stop the scollbar jumping around so ridiculously.

Comment: the fiddle on this was broken due to some problems with github not being a proper cdn and it couldn't get the js file to load.. fixed it with 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZLhAd/205/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work and I cannot get it to work on my site. Getting an error that quicksearch is not a function. Using chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). Also tried firefox 52.0 (32-bit)

Comment: @nwolybug - Fixed it, in the future, try looking at the console output - it tells you exactly what the problem is.  See the updated example and jsfiddle (linked in my answer now)

Answer (score 9):

OK, here's a different take, using keypress directly:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/VFVZL/1/

Basically, bind keypress and use that:

```
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
    $('#typed').append(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    if (!findString($('#typed').text())) {
        $('#typed').text('');
    }
});
```

`findString` is just some vaguely cross browser page string finder.  See the fiddle for details.

Comment: Any thoughts on whether this is any better/worse than your other answer? Your other answer works damn well!

Comment: well, this one doesn't have to have any additional UI - i.e. you could skip having the `#typed` div visible at all.  Also, the other one only really works on a table, whereas this one will find text in any place within the document.  I agree that the other one is nicer though :)

Comment: I have a bad feeling about how this might interact with normal browser handling of key events or other things in the system. It might not do anything bad, but it seems better to do things in a more normal way unless there is a particularly good reason not to, which is not the case here. It smells to me like the kind of approach that could lead to unforeseen and hard to identify interactions with other things in the system... similar to using too broad scope in general programming.

Answer (score 1):

There's this prototype which is **NOT** recommended (as of 19/07/21) to be used on PROD sites , but if you want to give a try , then it's pretty simple & best part is that it's 1st  party .

Just type this on your console in this stack overflow window itself :

```
window.find("Aniket");
```

More info can be found here -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find