# wordpress find text within a page and jump to location in page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to implement this into my wordpress page, but so far I have no luck because I do not know how to properly do it, and I need help

[JavaScript- find text within a page and jump to location in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327416/javascript-find-text-within-a-page-and-jump-to-location-in-page)

Also, I want to hide this search bar into a floating button, and it will only come out when users click on that button, kinda like Bootstrap floating action button

The reason why I want to have it on my website is because when people are on their phones, there are no keyboards to do Crtl+f in order to do a string/text search like how we can do it on pc/laptop.

Please help, I really appreciate it
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.